# js file(hosted) loaded through script tag in index.html is not downloaded by app

Tags: android, html, ios, angular, ionic-framework

We have an ionic ios app written using Angular and one of the script file is loaded by mentioning in index.html.
The script file is hosted and the ios app has been able to load the script file so far without issue

Code snippet:

```
<script src="/bi/assets/js/embed-api/v1/embed-api.min.js" type="text/javascript" de></script>
```

Strangely now the ios app doesn't load/download the script. I tried to include the domain name also in src like this and then the app magically loads:

```
<script src="https://www.xyz123.com/bi/assets/js/embed-api/v1/embed-api.min.js" type="text/javascript" de></script>
```

I am confused by this as to why a completely normal script loading would behave strange. Any theories for this behaviour is welcome